# Rails routes conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have few questions regarding rails routes conventions.

Let we've the routes as follows

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products, only: [:index]
  resource :cart, only: [:show]
  resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  root to: "products#index"
end
```

- My question is why is cart not pluralized like other resource.
- When should we pluralize resource?
- Instead of defining custom get and post routes is it better to use resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, you require a singular route, that is not referenced by an ID. For Example, `localhost:3000/me`.

So if you write `resource :me` in `routes.rb`, this will generate all routes for you, except the index route and the difference will be that none of the routes will be using an ID in case of Show, Edit, Update, Create and Destroy routes, as we are considering `me` to be a singular entity.

So, if you just want the singular route for your profile page, you will simply write

`resource :me, only: [:show]`

Answer (score 1):

1. as i know cart is a single property for each visitor and we don't have model for  cart (it is a concept), but we have a lot of products, products model and Index action to get list of all products. so because cart is a single property it is not pluralized.
   you can find difference between resource and resources in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356146)
2. resource preserve a list of standard actions (show, create, update, destroy...) and we can create all of tease standard routes with a single line, so by using resource our code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggest you to read [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) it contains answers for all your questions.

> My question is why is cart not pluralized like other resource.

Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. Define `resource :post` instead of `resources :post` you will have routes like `/post` instead of `/post/:post_id`  [ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

> When should we pluralize resource?

If you need an `ID` of records in the routes and it's required.

> Instead of defining custom get and post routes is it better to use resource?

If you have a basic RESTful routes, is better to use `resource(s)` method, because it's shorten to write `resources :post` instead of denote every action on it's own also less code == less bugs.