# Overriding routes parameters with NIL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Is there a way to use resource routing instead of writing the routes one by one if my methods for which the default expects parameters don't use parameters?

For example, if I had a routes file like below, the expected path for the `update` method would be like this: `/cats/:id` ([docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions))

```rb
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cats, only: [:create, :update]
end
```

However, I don't require any params for my `update` method, meaning the path should be `/cats`.
I know there's a way to [rename](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) the params and not use `:id`, but I didn't find anything on disabling them. I tried adding `param: nil` to the end of the line but it didn't work.

As I wrote initially, I know this can be done if I write the routes one by one like below. My question is whether I can use `resources` to do it. Thank you!

```rb
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'cats', to: 'cats#create'
  put 'cats', to: 'cats#update'
end
```

Comment: Try `resource` without pluralized 's'.

Comment: @7urkm3n Thank you, this worked!
For anyone viewing this question - see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356146/difference-between-resource-and-resources-in-rails-routing) for difference between `resource` and `resources`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the use case for singular resources. Quote from the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

> Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID. For example, you would like `/profile` to always show the profile of the currently logged in user.

Change our routing to

```
resource :cats, only: [:create, :update]
```

And the following routes will be created:

```
cats PATCH /cats(.:format)     cats#update
     PUT   /cats(.:format)     cats#update
     POST  /cats(.:format)     cats#create
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not, `resource` is just a helper to create the standard verb-based CRUD routes, if you want custom routes you need to define your update route the way you did in your second example, of course, you can still use `resource` for your `create` route and just pass `only: :create`.